# Wordsearch with directions saved in int array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to develop **a wordsearch which finds the word "OIE" (indicating how many times appears), based in an integer unidimensional array that saves the directions (8)**, but I get strange errors when I run this (and incorrect outputs).

This is the code:

```
    int arrf[8] = {0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1};
int arrc[8] = {-1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,-1};
char s[] = "OIE";

int main() {
    int n, m;
    while (cin >> n >> m) {
        int res = 0;
        vector<vector<char> > S(n, vector<char>(m));
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) cin >> S[i][j];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
                for (int d = 0; d < 8; ++d) {
                    bool trobat = true;
                    for (int h = 0; h < 3 and trobat; ++h) {
                        int f = i + arrf[d], c = j + arrc[d];
                        if (f < 0 || f >= n || c < 0 || c >= m || S[f][c] != s[h])
                            trobat = false;
                    }
                    if (trobat) res++;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << res << endl;
    }
}
```

Could somebody help me to fix this? I would appreciate.

Regards.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Is there a reason why you have the words "or" and "and" instead of their Boolean counterparts?

Comment: @bwtrent i think you mean logical counterparts.

Comment: @bwtrent Foreign keyboard I would guess.

Comment: In this case, **all outputs are 0 when the word** appears many times. For example, try with the input: [2 2 OIEEIO] or with any other.

Comment: I get this error with boolean counterparts, which I have forgotten there. (Sorry) @bwtrent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error is that this line

```
int f = i + arrf[d], c = j + arrc[d];
```

should be

```
int f = i + h*arrf[d], c = j + h*arrc[d];
```

With your code it doesn't matter how many times you go round the inner loop you are still checking the same position.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Good night. Regards :-)